# How can I generate source maps only for packages under my org scope in create react app when building

Tags: reactjs, webpack, create-react-app, source-maps

How can we generate source maps only for the app source code and for packages under some scope (e.g. `@mycompany/*`) and not for all node_modules packages in create-react-app, currently you can either create sourcemap by default or disable all source map creation (setting `GENERATE_SOURCEMAP` to false)